# Lighting not showing properly in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I've been shading a car for a while, all in viewport shading. I configured an HDRi so i could get some light with the EasyHDR add-on.

When i switched to the cycles render view, i get a weird bottom to top gradient light. I have Scene Lights and Scene World all checked. And all lights didn't work, including: Sun, Point, etc.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

[image: Viewport Cycles render of car]

[image: World]

Comment: Hello maybe show the Shader Editor for the World?

Comment: We need more information to help you. Screenshots of your lighting would help, as well as your shaders as mentioned above. In addition, you could share your blend file too, see the [File Sharing Guide](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene contains huge objects (125715m) that are hiden by View > Clip End parametr ...

[image]

... select all objects and search for **Frame All** ... screen appears empty, but it is not. Go to side panel (N) switch to *View* tab and change *Clip End* to 1.000.000 !!! (milion) :)

Comment: I can't believe that was it. Thank you so much.

Comment: It took me time to catch it :)